# Is there any limit on fetching maximum number of rows in sqllite?

Tags: sql, sqlite

Is there any limit of rows that we can fetch in sqllite db. for eg

```
var limitRow,offsetNo;
SELECT DISTINCT key, value, flags FROM testtable WHERE key LIKE 'hello%' LIMIT limitRow OFFSET offsetNo ;
```

what maximum value I can use here of `limitRow` variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but if you just want ALL the rows, you'd generally leave the LIMIT clause out of the query altogether:

```
SELECT DISTINCT key, value, flags FROM testtable WHERE key LIKE 'hello%';
```

Note that large result sets can bring your machine to its knees, though.